Effect of temperature on standard enthalpies
Does the changing of temperature have any effect on standard enthalpies (standard enthalpy of formation etc), and if so, what? If it does have an effect, then why do we define the standard state to be only 1 bar pressure and not include temperature in it? In other words, if a chemical reaction takes place at two different temperatures, does the change in enthalpy and entropy remain the same regardless of the temperature at which it takes place?

Hint: Are heat capacities of reactants and products always the same?

Usually 25C is the standard state temperature. And, yes, enthalpy and entropy are typically temperature dependent.

This question is similar to: Why could it be assumed that the standard enthalpy change is independent of temperature down to 25 °C?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The defintion of standard enthalpy flows down from IUPAC's definition of standard state (https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/S05925).  And that contains only a pressure designation (and, for solutions, concentration), not a temperature designation.
The reason is convenience and practicality:  Reactions are typically carried out at widely-varying temperatures, but at ambient pressure.  Further, unless it's a gas-phase reaction with different numbers of moles of gas phase reactants and products, deviations from ambient pressure due to elevation and weather will only have small effects.  Changes in temperature will, by contrast, typically have large effects.
The upshot is that, practically, pressure can be considered pretty much standard across most reactions, while temperature cannot. Thus, for convenience, it made sense to consider 1 bar as standard when formulating enthalpy tables, yet leave it up to the table formulator to specify the temperature.
And that's why a "standard enthalpy" is the enthalpy at 1 bar, but at your specified temperature.
The fact that standard enthalpies can be specified for varying temperatures does not mean that enthalpy is unaffected by temperature.  Indeed, it's quite the opposite: It's precisely because enthalpies do typically vary with temperature that the standard is constructed such that one is allowed to, and thus needs to, specify the temperature.

Yeah, that's the thing! Most P-chem courses for undergraduates fail to make it clear that standard quantities are not set in stone and unaffected by the context in which they are defined. There's a reason they are called 'standard' and not 'universal constants,' after all.

@theorist, so my chemistry textbook just blandly gave reactions and their standard enthalpies next to them without mentioning anything about temperature, but I felt that the enthalpy should vary as temperature varies and wanted it clarified. Thanks a lot.

Enthalpy, in general, is a function of temperature. In particular, there are a number of results in thermodynamics concerning the dependance of $\Delta H$ on T.
The simplest that comes to mind is that, by definition, given $H=H(T,\{x_i\})$:
$$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_{\{x_i\}}=C_p$$
So, the partial derivative of H with respect to temperature is the heat capacity at constant pressure (where pressure is held constant along with any other state variable of interest for the system).
If $C_p$ is not constant (and it is not, as we know from several experimental and theoretical results such as Debye's law ) then enthalpy cannot possibly be a monotonic non-increasing or non-decreasing function (that is, it cannot be a constant function) in the space of state variables where we held any other $x_i$ variable constant.
Given that, there is an obvious result that we can infer on the heat capacities in chemical reactions. Out of laziness, I will cite from wikipedia and add something useful at the end to generalize the results:

The variation of the enthalpy of reaction with temperature is given by Kirchhoff's_law_of_thermochemistry, which states that the temperature derivative of $\Delta H$ for a chemical reaction is given by the difference in heat capacity (at constant pressure) between products and reactants:


$$\left(\frac{\partial \Delta H}{\partial T}\right)_p = \Delta C_p$$


Integration of this equation permits the evaluation of the heat of reaction at one temperature from measurements at another temperature [n.d.a consult a standard textbook in physical chemistry on this matter, see the references at the end of the answer].

In particular, we can write Kirkhoff's law in its integral form considering:
$$\text{d}\Delta H= \left(\frac{\partial \Delta H}{\partial T}\right)_{\{x_i\}}\text{d}T + \sum_{i}\left(\frac{\partial \Delta H}{\partial x_i}\right)_T\text{d}x_i $$
If we held constant any other variable during the chemical reaction, then:
$$\text{d}\Delta H = \Delta C_p \text{d}T \implies \int_{T_0}^{T}\text{d}\Delta H = \int_{T_0}^{T}\Delta C_p \text{d}T$$
That is, in final formulas:
$$\Delta H (T) = \Delta H (T_0) + \int_{T_0}^{T}\Delta C_p \text{d}T$$
Then, it becomes a matter of knowing the dependance of $\Delta C_p$ on temperature. Usually, in introductory courses, one makes the assumption that for small temperature intervals:
$$\Delta H (T) = \Delta H (T_0) + \Delta C_p\int_{T_0}^{T} \text{d}T = \Delta H (T_0) + \Delta C_p (T-T_0)$$.
This crude result works wonders in many cases but I much prefer the derivation you can find in Castellan's "Physical Chemistry" (a quite old textbook but really intriguing nonetheless).
Basically, assuming a power series expansion like the one you would use for the virial equation of real gases, you can write:
$$\Delta C_p =a+bT+cT^2+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n T^{n}$$
Thus leading to:
$$\Delta H (T) = \Delta H (T_0) + \int_{T_0}^{T}\Delta C_p \text{d}T=$$
$$= \Delta H (T_0) + \int_{T_0}^{T} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n T^{n}\text{d}T = \Delta H (T_0) + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\int_{T_0}^{T}  T^{n}\text{d}T$$ =
$$=\Delta H (T_0) + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\left[\frac{T^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]$$
I will add the references to both Atkins and Castellan's textbooks as soon as possible.

An alternative is using the Hess law, which is equivalent to the Kirchhoff law.

True! I will add a remark, actually I think that Kirchhoff 's law derives directly from the Hess Law, considering $\Delta_r H=\sum_i b_i\Delta^0_f H_i -\sum_j a_j \Delta^0_f H_j$ for the general reaction $\sum a_j \ce{A_j} \ce{->} \sum b_i \ce{B_i}$

I think so as well. The Kirchhoff Law is a special case of the Hess law, but is IMHO possibly less known to students than the latter.

Absolutely, yes! This is why I wrote the full derivation. Generally speaking, I feel that P-chem should always be taught with full derivations and (reasonably) rigorous proofs. I've seen professors present the Debye-Hückel formulas without even explaining what the Poisson-Boltzmann equation is, which leads students to confusion in understanding Debye's screening parameter and failing the exam.
